# (iOS8) set the status bar to light content

Tags: ios, ios8

How do I set the status bar to light content in iOS8? I've seen answers for iOS7 but they are not working?

I've changed it here:

[image]

and on the controller itself with no luck.

**Edit - added requested screenshot of status bar**

[image]

Comment: Screenshot of the status bar?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

- Step 1: Head over to your project's info.plist.
- Step 2: Change the settings for "View controller-based status bar
  appearance" to NO. If this key is not visible, simply add it by
  pressing the plus button. Should look like this.
- Step 3: In your target, option General, In Deployment info. You
  should change Status Bar Style to Light (See attached image).

[image]

Hope this helps!
[image]

Comment: Perfect. I just had to add the field to the `info.plst` the code step 3 was not required.

Comment: I just checked, step 3 is only required if you want to set the Status Bar Style programmatically instead of using the app settings like you did! :)

Comment: it's showing error CGContextRestoreGState  if you are using iOS 9 device to test app.

Comment: The step 3 is deprecated since iOS 9

Comment: The step 3  since iOS 9 look like `UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent`

Comment: Thanks you so much. I added the step 2 and it works perfectly.